# pycuda - memcpy_dtoh, not giving what appears to have been set

Tags: numpy, cuda, pycuda

I have a very simple function where I'm passing in a char array and doing a simple character match.  I want to return an array of 1/0 depending on which characters are matched.

Problem: although I can see the value has been set in the data structure (as I print it in the function after it's assigned) when the int array is copied back from the device the values aren't as expected.

I'm sure it's something silly.

```py
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy as np

mod = SourceModule("""
__global__ void test(const char *q, const int chrSize, int *d, const int intSize) {
    int v = 0;
    if( q[threadIdx.x * chrSize] == 'a' ||  q[threadIdx.x * chrSize] == 'c' ) {
        v = 1;
    }
    d[threadIdx.x * intSize] = v;
    printf("x=%d, y=%d, val=%c ret=%d\\n", threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y, q[threadIdx.x * chrSize], d[threadIdx.x * intSize]);
}
""")
func = mod.get_function("test")

# input data
a = np.asarray(['a','b','c','d'], dtype=np.str_)
# allocate/copy to device
a_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(a_gpu, a)

# destination array
d = np.zeros((4), dtype=np.int16)
# allocate/copy to device
d_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(d.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(d_gpu, d)

# run the function
func(a_gpu, np.int8(a.dtype.itemsize), d_gpu, np.int8(d.dtype.itemsize), block=(4,1,1))

# copy data back and priint
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(d, d_gpu)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
x=0, y=0, val=a ret=1
x=1, y=0, val=b ret=0
x=2, y=0, val=c ret=1
x=3, y=0, val=d ret=0
[1 0 0 0]
```

Expected output:

```
x=0, y=0, val=a ret=1
x=1, y=0, val=b ret=0
x=2, y=0, val=c ret=1
x=3, y=0, val=d ret=0
[1 0 1 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main problems, neither of which have anything to do with `memcpy_dtoh`:

1. You have declared `d` and `d_gpu` as dtype `np.int16`, but the kernel is expecting C++ `int`, leading to a type mistmatch. You should use the `np.int32` type to define the arrays.
2. The indexing of `d` within the kernel is incorrect. If you have declared the array to the compiler as a 32 bit type, indexing the array as `d[threadIdx.x]` will automatically include the correct alignment for the type. Passing and using `intSize` to the kernel for indexing `d` is not required and it is incorrect to do so.

If you fix those two issues, I suspect the code will work as intended.